# How to plot different lines over ggplot? "Group = variable" doesn't work?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I was using the babynames dataset. Filtered the male names, that were given the most often in at least one year. That are eight names in total. Now I want to plot the development of the `proportion` variable over the years for every of these eight names in one plot.

```
    babynames %>%
  filter(sex == "M") %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(rank = min_rank(desc(n))) %>%
  filter(rank ==1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(name)
```

Thats how I got the names.

```
 babynames %>%
  filter(name %in% c("John", "Robert", "James", "Michael", "David",
                     "Jacob", "Noah", "Liam")) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = year, y = prop, color = name, group = name))
```

With this code, I get the figure you see in picture one:

[image]

When I use geom_point it looks fine. I don't understand, why `group=name` doesn't do the trick.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood well, but do you want a continuous line (same shape as in geom point but with line)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I just found the solution.
I forgot to filter not just the names, but also sex == "M", because otherwise there are different points for one year and therefore vertcial lines. So that works:

babynames %>%
  filter(name %in% c("John", "Robert", "James", "Michael", "David",
                     "Jacob", "Noah", "Liam"), sex "M") %>%
  ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = year, y = prop, color = name, group = name))

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't aggregated (or alternatively, filtered) the `sex` variable. This can be verified by applying `facet_wrap()`:

```
babynames::babynames %>%
    filter(name %in% c("John", "Robert", "James", "Michael", "David",
                       "Jacob", "Noah", "Liam")) %>%
    ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x = year, y = prop, color = name)) +
    facet_wrap(~sex)
```

[image]